PowerShell "Select -First 10" returns all results
I'm attempting to get an hourly report from Powershell Get-ExchangeOnline about the number of external spam messages to my users.  It's working OK but I'd like to see just the top ten recipients.  Supposedly "Select -First 10" should accomplish it.
This example code returns the same whether it includes the last section or not.  What can I do to trim the results?

Get-MessageTrace -Status FilteredAsSpam -RecipientAddress @example.com -StartDate (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) -EndDate (Get-Date) | Where-Object {$_.SourceContext -notlike "@example.com" } | Group-Object RecipientAddress | Select Name,Count | Sort Count -Descending | Select Name,Count -First 10


I cannot reproduce the problem. It shows exactly the desired result.

Which PowerShell version?

Currently using 5.1.22621.4391 .  I was able to get what I wanted using " | Sort Count -Descending | Select-Object -First 10" .  Thanks for the assistance!
